# Chatbot in python generates random answers if the userinput contains more than one word

Tags: python

My problem is, that my program randomly generates a random answer if the userinput contains more than one word, even though i don't want to. I mean i understand why the programm  generates a random answer, but how can i overcome this?

Here is my code:

```
import random

print("Welcome to Chatbot! Have fun.")
print("")
randomanswer = ['Thats not good', 'me too', 'how about you?']
reactionanswer = {'hello': 'hello, whats up?',
                  'sad': 'speak to me',
                  'entertainment': 'how can i entertain you?'}
userinput = ''
while True:
    userinput = input("Question/Answer: ")
    userinput = userinput.lower()
    if userinput == 'bye':
        print("See you soon!")
        break
    else:
        usersplit = userinput.split()
        for i in usersplit:
            if i in reactionanswer:
                print(reactionanswer[i])
            else:
                print(random.choice(randomanswer))
```

Comment: please include intended output and the output you are getting in your question.

Comment: @python_beginner you iterating over `userinput.split()` that contain list of splitted words from input. 2 words = list with 2 elements ...

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me, I ran exactly your code and get this:

```
Question/Answer: hello guy
hello, whats up?
Thats not good

Question/Answer: nothing in the list
me too
me too
me too
Thats not good
```

work also for several words. it depend on what works meaning - you wrote that for each word that not in your known list it would generate random answer. and for any known word it will answer as you want to. and that exactly what happen - in the first case the first word generated the first known answer and the second generated random answer. clarify what exactly not work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that even though you found your answer the for loop continues to run. Add add "break" statement if the word has been found in answers. Like this:

```
    else:
        usersplit = userinput.split()
        for i in usersplit:
            if i in reactionanswer:
                print(reactionanswer[i])
                break < --- add this
            else:
                print(random.choice(randomanswer))
```